# Portuguese dictionary empty in Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, dictionary

I just installed the Portuguese dictionary on Ubuntu 13.10 but no application is able to use it. Checking in the command line it seems this dictionary is empty:

```
$ sudo aptitude search aspell-pt
p   aspell-pt                                                 - Portuguese dictionaries for GNU Aspell (old package)               
p   aspell-pt-br                                              - Brazilian Portuguese dictionary for GNU Aspell                     
i   aspell-pt-pt                                              - European Portuguese dictionary for GNU Aspell  
$ aspell dicts | grep pt
pt_PT
$ aspell -l pt_PT dump master
$
```

Could I be missing some package or is this a bug that should be reported?

Since there's no Portuguese dictionary for LibreOffice 4.1, having one for aspell becomes indispensable.

Thanks.

**Update**: I installed the pt_BR dictionary and it seems to be functional. The `dump master` command displays the full vocabulary. So this is only affecting the pt_PT dictionary, precisely the one I need.

**Update II**: This issue persists in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: This fix was successfully tested in Trusty. The dictionary file is updated to the latest version.

I finally managed to solved this problem. This is [a bug that first appeared in Lucid](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/myspell.pt/+bug/568088) and persisted with Oneiric. For some reason it has re-emerged in Saucy. The difficulty was then to find a source for the dictionary, which eventually [I did](http://natura.di.uminho.pt/download/sources/Dictionaries/aspell6). The fix is then:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://natura.di.uminho.pt/download/sources/Dictionaries/aspell6/aspell6.pt-preao-20150102.tar.bz2
tar xjf aspell6.pt-preao-20150102.tar.bz2
cd aspell6-pt_PT-preao-20150102-0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```